# Upgraded to Lion with an application in Snow Leopard called LaunchPad

Tags: mac

Recently I upgraded my laptop from Snow Leopard to Lion.  However in Snow Leopard, I fooled around with the system a bit and "named" an app called LaunchPad.app(It's actually called quickpick)  Now in Lion, it retained the old app and didn't change it to the actual LaunchPad.  When I try to delete the LaunchPad app now, it says the it is necessary for the system and I can't delete it.  What should I do now?  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Time Machine backup of your current system, reinstall Lion, restore everything but applications from backup, then restore the other applications manually from Time Machine.

---

If you're feeling adventurous, and have good current backups, you could launch Terminal and enter the following **exactly as shown**:

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/LaunchPad.app
```

Enter your password and the application should be removed.

Now you shouldn't have LaunchPad.app anymore. You could try to get LaunchPad from a friend, by installing a 10.7.2 combo updater, or by reinstalling Lion.

Comment: The first option (of restoring a backup without `/Applications/`) seems much more adventurous to me than `rm -rf`ing Launchpad.app.

Comment: @Lri Well, where do you get the real Launchpad.app from? Also, adventurous because I have no idea whether OS X requires that application even when the feature is unused, or if it's just cosmetic.

Comment: I don't think the OP even has the actual Launchpad... Actually, Launchpad.app isn't even required for Launchpad to work. (But `Dock.app` is.) Seems like it exists just to be an alternative way to display the Launchpad screen.

Comment: @Lri hm…  You are right.  The LaunchPad.app in the applications folder isn't necessary for the launchpad to work.  I can activate it using hot corners.  And Daniel Beck, I've already deleted the app.  Now I'm just waiting for my friend to get online to send it to me.  Thanks guys. :)